# How to divide dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary comprising of keys and values as integers in a lists, e.g.,

```py
input: {
    'example_key1': [358, 57, 18602, 18388],
    'example_key2': [415, 12, 4800, 2013],
    'example_key3': [450, 10, 4500, 4500],
}
```

I wish to divide the last value with the second to last value in the list for every key, multiply the answer by 100 and enter the answer into a similar dictionary with with ndigit = 1 point round.

```py
output: {
    'example_key1': [98.8],   # [round((((18388 / 18602)) * 100), 1)]
    'example_key2': [41.9],   # [round((((2103 / 4800)) * 100), 1)]
    'example_key3': [100.0],  # [round((((4500 / 4500)) * 100), 1)]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (d is your input dict):

```
res={i:round(d[i][-1]/d[i][-2]*100, 1) if d[i][-2]!=0 else 0.0 for i in d}

print(res)

{'example_key1': 98.8, 'example_key2': 41.9, 'example_key3': 100.0}
```

Comment: Very helpful oneliner, thank you! Hypothetically asking, can this also write a 0.0 value in the output dict if `input dict = {'example_key4' :  [0, 0, 0, 0]}`

Comment: I updated the code so that it will return 0.0 in case that second to last element is zero

Answer (score 7):

You can use dict-comprehension:

```
d = {
'example_key1': [358, 57, 18602, 18388],
'example_key2': [415, 12, 4800, 2013],
'example_key3': [450, 10, 4500, 4500]
}

out = {
    k: [round((j / i) * 100, 1)]
    for k, (*_, i, j) in d.items()
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'example_key1': [98.8], 'example_key2': [41.9], 'example_key3': [100.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
input = {
    'example_key1': [358, 57, 18602, 18388],
    'example_key2': [415, 12, 4800, 2013],
    'example_key3': [450, 10, 4500, 4500]
}

rounded_values = list(map(lambda item: round((item[3] / item[2]) * 100, 1), input.values()))
output_dict = dict()

for key, value in zip(input.keys(), rounded_values):
    output_dict[key] = value

print(output_dict)
```