# how to divide between values in inline dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have studied [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dictionary-comprehension-in-python-dict-comprehensions-explained/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209481/how-to-divide-dictionary-values), but still fail too.

this is my code:

```
d1 = {"Overall_Value" : 21600, "Unit_Number": 48}
```

i just want to divide value in dictionary 21600/48

The output I want is: 450.

Thank you

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Are you asking how to get the values of the two keys, and then divide those values by each other?

Comment: i want to divide the value 21600/48 so the output is 450 That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you actually do not need to use a dictionary comprhension here, just simple dictionary access and division.

Try this runnable example:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

d1 = {"Overall_Value" : 21600, "Unit_Number": 48}
r = d1["Overall_Value"]/d1["Unit_Number"]
print("r=",r)
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Dictionary comprehensions are used to concisely construct a dictionary using the output of an inline for loop. So if you had a bunch of records and you wanted to convert all of them into a dictionary, **then** you might use a dictionary comprehension like this...

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

many_records = [
{"id":"a", "Overall_Value" : 21600, "Unit_Number": 48},
{"id":"b", "Overall_Value" : 2200, "Unit_Number": 24},
]
many_outputs = {d["id"]: d["Overall_Value"]/d["Unit_Number"] for d in many_records}
print("many_outputs=", many_outputs)
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```